# How to dynamically size custom mvxtableviewcell after binding via MVVMCROSS

Tags: ios, uitableview, binding, uitextview, mvvmcross

I am trying to create a table consisting of a custom mvxtableviewcell that contains a label (Heading) and a UITextView(body).

I'm using MvxSimpleTableViewSource as source type.

Im binding the table source via mvvmcross to a list containing objects of (heading, body) thats is populated with data from a web service.

Is it possible to have the cells recalculate its hight when the textview is populated with data from the web service?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to have the cells recalculate its hight when the textview is populated with data from the web service?

Yes - but you have to wire up a more complete `TableViewSource` which provides a dynamically sizing cell and a `GetHeightForRow` implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
I have implemented a method in my custom cell that calculates the height of the cell based on the size of the `UITextview` inside the cell. Then i my mvxsimpletablesource I have overrided the `GetHeightForRow` where I call the method in the cell that calculates the height. I think I need to call the reloadData after the UITextview is populated somehow, is this the correct approach?